# CIFilters and AVVideoCompositionInstructions

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

In my app, I have to apply filters on playback. I do this by using AVVideoComposition and apply the filter on each frame.

For some reasons however, when I change the videoComposition of my AVPlayerItem the video rotates. I tried to fix this problem by using a transformation and add it the videoComposition instructions. The rotation problem is fixed, but the filter is not applied anymore.

How can I both fix the rotation while stil having my filter applied ?

Code below:

```
- (void)setVideoComposition:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)videoComposition {
_videoComposition = videoComposition;

AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoCompositionTrack =
    [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
        preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [_avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].lastObject;

CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration);

[videoCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:range
    ofTrack:videoAssetTrack
    atTime:kCMTimeZero
    error:nil];

AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction =
    [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = range;

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction =
    [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction
        videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoCompositionTrack];

[layerInstruction setTransform:videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform
    atTime:kCMTimeZero];



NSMutableArray *instructions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id instr in _videoComposition.instructions) {
    [instructions addObject:instr];
}

[instructions insertObject:instruction atIndex:0];

_videoComposition.instructions = instructions;

// Hook it to the item player.
if (self.playerItem) {
    self.playerItem.videoComposition = _videoComposition;
}
```

Comment: If you share some code, we can help

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: One note. If I apply the filter just normally, it rotates as I said but when I close and open the app I get the correct result.

Comment: Where do you add other filters to `_videoComposition.instructions`? It seems it is already empty in your code. And it contains just `instruction` which is inserted to index 0.